# Strange pointer behaviour in loop

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers

I can't figure out why is this code not working. (I know how to fix it, but I'm interested in this particular solution) It takes one string and puts is on the end of other string. `x = "abc"`, `y = "def"` and after executing foo, `x = "abcdef"`. After executing my code I only get `"abc"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

void foo(char *x, char *y){
    while(*x++);
    while(*y){
        *x++ = *y++;
    }
    *x = '\0';
}

int main(void){
    char x[MAX+1], y[MAX+1];
    scanf("%s %s", x, y);
    foo(x, y);
    printf("%s", x);
    return 0;
}
```

If I do this, the code works perfectly fine.

```
while(*x) x++;
```

Comment: Are you asking for the difference between `while(*x++);` and `while(*x) x++;`? If so, most of your code is irrelevant.

Comment: `while(*x++);` will increment `x` after the null is found. `while(*x) x++;` will not.

Comment: @juanchopanza He is not asking that specifically. The code he's giving is part of the problem that he has developed, so it's not useless!

Comment: comments on current code: 1) this: 'int main(void){' should be: 'int main(){' 2) returned value from scanf() should be checked to assure operation was successful 3) it would be easy for the user to overrun the input buffers, so put a max input char count on the '%s' format specifiers in scanf() 4) foo() should check the lengths of the strings in x and y to assure the concat of those strings will fit in x. 5) foo() is currently keeping the string terminator nul byte from x, it should overwrite it

Comment: @user3629249 Actually in C it's correct to type int main(void) when function doesn't take any arguments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This expression will increment `x` even after the null is discovered and the loop completes:

```
while(*x++);
```

In this case, you are appending the second string AFTER the null, so that part of the string isn't "seen". The string becomes `"abc\0def"`.

The following will NOT increment `x` when the null is found, so `*x` will point to null after the loop completes:

```
while(*x) x++;
```

Therefore, in this case, your string comes out correctly as, `"abcdef"`.

Comment: @Gopi Right, but it is post-increment, so the de-reference is applied to the pointer before the increment.

Answer (score 6):

This loop:

```
while(*x++);
```

moves `x` past the null terminator. So your c-string ends at the same place as it did before. The characters in `y` are written to `x`, but they come *after* the null terminator, so they are not printed out.

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
while(*x++);
```

`x` points to one past the null character at the end of the statement. In effect, you end up with

```
x[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\0', ....}
```

in `main`.